# Get the id of every div behind a draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielmbcn/m6WUT/).

I have a draggable area divided into five subareas, each one with its corresponding id. The point is that I want to retrieve the id of each subarea when the draggable is over them, and print out the result. But I can't manage to do it since I'm using Javascript's onmouseover method and, while dragging it, the mouse is all the time pointing to the draggable, not to the subareas directly.

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="barra_draggable">

    <div id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-header"></div>
    <div class="franja_exp" onmouseover="printid(this);" id="five_years"></div>
    <div class="franja_exp" onmouseover="printid(this);" id="four_years"></div>
    <div class="franja_exp" onmouseover="printid(this);" id="three_years"></div>
    <div class="franja_exp" onmouseover="printid(this);" id="two_years"></div>
    <div class="franja_exp" onmouseover="printid(this);" id="one_year"></div>
</div>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

function printid (elm){
    resultado.innerHTML = "" + elm.id;
}

$("#draggable5").draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

What could be done here for retrieving the ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make the other elements "droppable" ...this way you can get the ids via the over function:

```
$(".franja_exp").droppable({over:function(event,ui){
    resultado.innerHTML = "" + this.id;
    //or: printid(this);
}});
```

in your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m6WUT/11/

Comment: Oh nice, thank you :) I didn't imagine it was this easy!